# What's the meaning of "take" here?

Tags: word-meaning

The verb "take" has many meanings and I cannot understand the meaning of "take" in the text below.

> I stood outside the bishop’s office on a cold night in February. I didn’t
>   know what had taken me there.

Could you please tell me what the meaning of "take" here is?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your sentence;

> I didn’t know what had taken me there.

Although there's a difference of perspective between **take** and **bring** I'd paraphrase it as:

> I didn’t know what had **brought** me there.

See usage note of [bring](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/bring), which says:

> *Bring* indicates motion toward the place from which the action is regarded—typically toward the speaker—while *take* indicates motion away from the place from which the action is regarded—typically away from the speaker. Thus from a customer's perspective, the customer *takes* checks to the bank and *brings* home cash, while from the banker's perspective the customer *brings* checks to the bank in order to *take* away cash. When the point of reference is not the place of speaking itself, either verb is possible, but the correct choice still depends on the desired perspective.

Answer (score 12):

I don't know what caused me to go to that place.

> 15 a : **to** lead, carry, or **cause to go along to another place**

[Take (Merriam-Webster)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/take)

> My wanderings took me to Waterstones Trafalgar Square, where I had my
>   very first UK book signing in 2000 for my very first book
>
> My wanderings took me to a place near the Sacred Rock.
>
> My wanderings took me to the Folkmoot Friendship Center
>
> Today, my wanderings took me to Embo

Comment: Or perhaps *motivated*, in place of *caused*.